Lambda function to PutRecord on Kinesis Stream ETIMEDOUT Error
I am writing a very simple lambda in JS. Its main purpose is to take the message from SQS (that i am triggering manually from AWS console) and then publish to kinesis stream through a put record. I have given the required permission to the lambda for PutRecord. But most of the time i am getting the below error.
  "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
  "errorMessage": "Error [ERR_HTTP2_STREAM_CANCEL]: The pending stream has been canceled (caused by: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.223.45.15:443)",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error [ERR_HTTP2_STREAM_CANCEL]: The pending stream has been canceled (caused by: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.223.45.15:443)",
    "    at process.<anonymous> (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1276:17)",
    "    at process.emit (node:events:517:28)",
    "    at emit (node:internal/process/promises:149:20)",
    "    at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:283:27)",
    "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:32)"
  ]
}

However surprisingly sometimes it would work too especially when i deploy by changing the partitionKey to a different random value.
import { KinesisClient, PutRecordCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-kinesis";

export const KINESIS_CLIENT = new KinesisClient([
  {
    httpOptions: {
      connectTimeout: 10000,
    },
    maxRetries: 1,
    region: 'us-west-2',
  },
]);

export const handler = async (event) => {

  const promises = [];

  for (const {messageId, body} of event.Records) {
    processEvent(body)
    promises.push(processEvent(body));
  }

  const responses = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
  responses.forEach((response) => {
    if (response.status !== "fulfilled") {
      throw Error(JSON.stringify(responses));
    }
  });
};

export async function processEvent(body) {
  const newBody = JSON.parse(body);
  newBody['field'] = 'Random';

  await KINESIS_CLIENT.send(
      new PutRecordCommand({
        Data: new TextEncoder().encode(JSON.stringify(newBody)),
        StreamName: 'InputEventStream',
        PartitionKey: '3', <--- I change this and sometimes after redeployment it seems to work
      }),
  );
}```



Do you have the lambda in a VPC with a mix of private and public subnets but did not restrict the lambda to only be in the private subnets?

More than likely. I do have a vpc where other lambda are and i assigned the same VPC to this one. Could this be the issue? It works sometimes thought ocassionally but fails mostly

@luk2303 Was wondering why that would be an issue? I do have a vpc where another lambda currently sits. Would appreciate some insight

The second part of my comment is the important one: is the lambda configured to only be put in  the private subnets?

No, it is assigned a VPC that is common to another lambda

That is not what I am saying, I am talking about the subnets of the VPC the lambda is configured to use.

luk2302 is right. Both the calls to get the SQS message and the PUT to the Kinesis are HTTP requests that are routed through the public network. You have to run your lambda in a subnet that has a route to a NAT gateway or instance.

If I understand correctly, you have a Lambda trigger that fires off when a message is being put in a SQS. Assuming this scenario as true, the PUT call to the Kinesis is a normal HTTP request that is routed through the public network. You have to run your lambda in a subnet that has a route to a NAT gateway or NAT instance.
Alternatively, if your constraints doesn't allow you to deploy a Lambda in such a subnet, you could opt for a VPC Endpoint for Kinesis.

While you already set connectTimeout to 10 seconds, you might want to set both the socketTimeout (for read/write operations) and maxAttempts (for retries) explicitly.
export const KINESIS_CLIENT = new KinesisClient({
  region: 'us-west-2',
  maxAttempts: 3, // Allows more retry attempts
  requestHandler: new NodeHttpHandler({
    connectionTimeout: 20000, // 20 seconds connection timeout
    socketTimeout: 20000 // 20 seconds socket timeout
  })
});

Improved Error Handling
promises.push(processEvent(body).catch((err) => {
  console.error("Error processing record:", err);
  return err; // Capture error instead of failing immediately
}));


Thanks a lot, but can you kindly format the code a little? ALso i am not sure where to import NodeHttpHandler from

import { NodeHttpHandler } from "@aws-sdk/node-http-handler";
But i am still getting task timeout after 30 seconds

More error handling will help you debug this further.
